# How to create search function for JSON codable structure data in TableView using Swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My scenario, I created `UITableView` with below structured `JSON` data load. I need to add `global` search for `firstname`, `price`,  `date`, `title` and `description`. Here, I tried but it didn’t worked well for me. Please give me some solution.

For e.g.: User `searched` by `name` or `price`,  `date`, `title` and `description` UITableView should sortout list.

My Codable Struture

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let message: String
    let ode: Int
    let data: [Datum]
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title, description: String
    let price: Int
    let user: User
    let Appcode: Appcode
    let Appbase: Appbase

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case userID = "userid"
        case title, description
        case price
        case Date = "date"
        case location, user
        case appcode = "appcode”
        case appbase = "appbase”
    }
} 

struct Appcode: Codable {
    let card: String
}

struct Appbase: Codable {
    let base: String
}

struct User: Codable {
    let firstname, lastname: String
}
```

My Tableview Code

```
    var tableArray = [Datum]()
    var filteredResults = [Datum]()
    lazy var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar() 
    var isSearching = false

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if isSearching {
            return filteredResults.count
        } else {
            return self.tableArray.count
        }
        return 0
    }
```

My Search bar code

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" { //
            isSearching = false
            view.endEditing(true)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else {
            isSearching = true
            filteredResults = tableArray.filter({ value -> Bool in
                guard let text =  searchBar.text else { return false}
                return value.description.contains(text) // According to title from JSON
            })
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code cannot work anyway because the CodingKeys don't match the struct members in `Datum`.

Comment: Could you please post some solution. I am trying from long time cant able to fix this. atlas i need to set search for firstname @vadian

Comment: could you please provide some solution regarding this @vadian

Answer (score 0):

In your struct Datum your CodingKeys don't match your property names

> The names of the enumeration cases should match the names you've given to the corresponding properties in your type.

If you update your struct like this:

```
struct Datum: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title, description: String
    let price: Int
    let user: User
    let appCode: Appcode
    let appBase: Appbase

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case title, description
        case price
        case user
        case appCode = "appcode"
        case appBase = "appbase"
    }
}
```

You can later filter the array of elements like this:

```
let datum1 = Datum(id: 1, title: "test", description: "test1", price: 10, user: User(firstname: "a", lastname: "b"), appCode: Appcode(card: "app"), appBase: Appbase(base: "base"))

let datum2 = Datum(id: 1, title: "test", description: "test2", price: 10, user: User(firstname: "a", lastname: "b"), appCode: Appcode(card: "app"), appBase: Appbase(base: "base"))

let datum3 = Datum(id: 1, title: "test", description: "test3", price: 10, user: User(firstname: "a", lastname: "b"), appCode: Appcode(card: "app"), appBase: Appbase(base: "base"))

let array = [datum1, datum2, datum3]
array.filter{$0.user.firstname == "a"}
array.filter{$0.description.contains("2")}
```